# where("id not in (?) AND id != ?", current_user.friend_ids, current_user)のコードの意味

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
where("id not in (?) AND id != ?", current_user.friend_ids, current_user)
```

と書かれたコードがありまして、コードの記述の意味がわかりません。
このコードはツイッターのようなサイトの”友達を探す”ページのコントローラーの一部です。
まず、`"id not in (?) AND id != ?"`の部分の意味がわかりません。なぜANDを使っているのか 、(?) はどのような意味なのかid != ?がどんなことを意味しているのかさっぱりわかりません。どなたかこのコードの記述の仕方とその意味を教えてください。

ちなみにコントローラーのコードの全体は
find_friends_controller.rb

```
class FindFriendsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.where("id not in (?) AND id != ?", current_user.friend_ids, current_user).paginate(page: params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

のようになっています。

どうしてあんな複雑で難解なコードで友達が探せるのか疑問です。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where("id not in (?) AND id != ?", current_user.friend_ids, current_user)
```

この `?` の部分には、後続のパラメータが順番に埋め込まれます。コメントとして埋め込んでみると、

```
id not in (/*friend_ids*/) AND id != /*current_user*/
```

といった形になります。このクエリはUserモデルに対して投げていますから、

- `id not in (/*friend_ids*/)` 現在の友達のIDリストに含まれない＝まだ友達でない
- `AND` かつ
- `id != /*current_user*/` 自分自身でもない

という条件を満たすユーザーを列挙していることになります。

実際にはこの `where()` 呼び出しは `WHERE id not in (1,2,3,...) AND id != 8` といった形に変換され、SQLに埋め込まれることになります。ですから `where()` で使う式がどのような構造になっていて、何が書けるのかは、SQLのWHERE句について調べるとよいでしょう。

例えば： [SELECT構文：WHEREで検索条件を設定する | Smart](http://rfs.jp/sb/sql/s03/03_2-2.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます！！助かりました！